# How to check if any values of an array is a substring of a column value in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have a table with a column `equipments VARCHAR(100)`. I put comma-separated equipment names as string into this column.

A sample value might be:

```
"PKM_119160.000, PKM_119160.135"
```

Now, I want to filter the values of this table using an array of equipment names, checking if any value of that array is a substring of `equipments`. So If I pass an array like

```
["PKM_119160.000", "PKM_119160.216"]
```

I need to fetch the above row as `"PKM_119160.000"` is a substring of `"PKM_119160.000, PKM_119160.135"`. I could use `IN` if the `equipments` column contains single equipment name.

How can I get the proper values here? What should I do now? TIA

Comment: *I put comma-separated equipment names as string into this column* - that is the source of all evil in your case - **don't do this!** - this violates even the first normal-form of relational database design. If you have multiple values to store - use a child table!

Comment: While it is possible to compensate violation of 1NF in table design with lots of code you lose the main advantage of using a database. If you change to a header/detail table(s) design your "problem" becomes a simple join which will perform much better.

Comment: IN denotes a table operation. This will not work with strings. While you can use LIKE this is not safe. SQL Server does not have built-in REGEX functionality. For splitting a string like this refer to Jeff Modens excellent splitter function> https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function

Comment: Thank you very much all for your nice comments. I am going to change the database, creating a child table as referred by @marc_s. Thank you very much for the suggestions